# Where is the linux kernel elf file located?

Tags: linux-kernel, elf

If the Linux kernel by itself is an ELF file, where can I find its ELF file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many systems you can find a compressed kernel in `/boot`, typically named `vmlinuz-$(uname -r)`. The ELF executable contained therein can be extracted using [the `extract-vmlinux` script](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/extract-vmlinux), available in the kernel source code:

```
extract-vmlinux /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) > vmlinux
```

The result is an ELF file:

```
$ file vmlinux
vmlinux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=b28d236fad2fb7d0eb9bbe6eac766fb04406da3f, stripped
```

(on x86-64).

If you’re building the kernel,

```
make vmlinux
```

will produce the ELF executable.

Comment: `make vmlinux` doesn't work. What `makefile` are you using?

Comment: The kernel’s Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

On a desktop/server you will usually find the kernel in `/boot`.

Look for a file called `vmlinuz-*` (depends on your distribution).

How the kernel is loaded: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/initrd.html